# Django - Modify field value after every query

Tags: django, django-models

I am fairly new to Django coming from Laravel background. I would like to modify a field value everytime I query it. For example, every time you query firstname@User you return the Capitalized firstname. In Laravel this is known as [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators) but apparantely Accessors have different meaning in Django. For my case, I have a key-value table called `Meta` where the `value` field can be of any type:

```
class Meta(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    value = models.TextField()
    model = models.ForeignKey('Model', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and upon getting the value `Meta.objects.get(key='foo')`, I would like to return [`ast.literal_eval(value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to convert the string expression to the correct respective type. I did some research and only found the following:

- Create a custom Field.
- Use `get_foo_display(self)` but this only works for ChoiceField as far as I understood.

What is the best choice to apply this function for everytime I query `value` filtering by the `key`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom field, but the easiest thing here is to use a property.

```
class Meta(models.Model):
    value = models.TextField()

    @property
    def converted_value(self):
        return ast.literal_eval(self.value)
```

Now you can access `my_meta.converted_value` whenever you need that converted value.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I knew that it would be easy to implement but I couldn't find it in the documentation. I don't know how I missed it from the documentation. Thanks alot

Comment: This is a general Python thing, so isn't specifically covered in the Django docs. Don't forget to accept the answer as a sign to future searchers that it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

a @property is a good approach, but if you will access a lot of time ast.literal_eval and the processing is costly, you can overrride the save method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):                                         
    super(Meta, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)                         
    self.__original_value = self.value

def save(self, **kwargs):
    if self.__original_value != self.value:
        self.value = ast.literal_eval(self.value)
    super(Meta, self).save()
```

The **init** will pick the value before the update

Comment: Performance wise your approach is better, but you forgot to add the logic in __init__ I think.. there should be `self.converted_value = ast.literal_eval(self.value)` and then in `save` function if they do not match then `converted_value = ast.literal_eval(self.value)`. Thank for the approach, once fixed I will choose your answer as it has better performance

Comment: hi, normally `self.value` in `__init__` is the old value (before the save()) so its already saved with `ast.literal_eval` in database